# Why can't the storage_share access my samba share? (ubuntu server 11.04)

Tags: samba, remote-access, ubuntu-11.04, permissions

The title says it all. I can't understand why the user can't access the share. My other user can but he's the owner and all. I'll post the samba logs and configurations here below.

**smb.conf shares** (it's the share "Public" which I'm trying to access):

```
# /media/Storage/Public Share
[Vector_Public]
   comment = Vector pulic share
   read only = no
   path = /media/Storage/Public
   guest ok = no
;   force user = server
   force group = storage_public
   create mask = 0770
   directory mask = 0770
   security mask = 0770
   force create mode = 0770
   force directory mode = 0770
   valid users = server storage_share
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   vfs objects = recycle
   recycle:repository = .deleted/%U
   recycle:keeptree = yes
   recycle:touch = yes
   recycle:versions = yes
   recycle:maxsize = 0


[Vector_Private]
   comment = Vector private share (Niklas)
   read only = no
   path = /media/Storage/Private
   guest ok = no
   force user = server
   force group = server
   create mask = 0770
   directory mask = 0770
   security mask = 0770
   force create mode = 0770
   force directory mode = 0770
   valid users = server
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   vfs objects = recycle
   recycle:repository = .deleted/%U
   recycle:keeptree = yes
   recycle:touch = yes
   recycle:versions = yes
   recycle:maxsize = 0
```

The logs for the attempted connection are posted [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/720071/). I set the log level to 3 so it's very long :)

**Directory permissions:**

```
drwxrwx--- 5 server storage_public 4096 2011-10-05 20:28 Public
```

Thank you all for any ideas and tips you might have! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of a flow of permissions. The user trying to access the share didn't have read permissions on the parent folder containing the shares and this somehow blocked his access. It all works now when this has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

Line 4 of your linked log is

```
    check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [VECTOR]\[niklas]@[NIKLAS-LAPTOP]
```

This means youz try to access as user "niklas", but the share definiton uses

```
    valid users = server storage_share
```

Which means: Only user "server" and user "storage_share" would have permission to access this share.
If you try to user groups, which are vaild to access these shares, then you should write

```
    valid users = @server @storage_share
```

which will accept all users in group "servers" and "storage_share" for this share.

Comment: That's strange, because the user I'm logging in with is called storage_share. It's what I type in when trying to access the share. I'll try that you said when I get home today.

Answer (score 0):

`chmod -R a+x /media` and try again.

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem. The "valid user" and the "* mask" parameters will restrict to some users. The cifs layer will block all other users.